# php redirect on successful login

Tags: php

I have a .php that registers a user by calling another php function but i dont know what the best way to redirect a user if the registration is successful. Is there an option other than header incase i want to echo something before i redirect?

```
<?
// processRegister.php
//////////////////////

// First include the class definition
include('UserClass.php');

// Next, create an instance of the class
$newUser = new User;

// Call the registerUser() method, passing in the required variables
$newUser->registerUser($userName, $userPassword);

// If it was an error, the class will kill the script, if not, it will reach this point
$newUser->displayUserInfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 4 methods, as you said using a header redirect:

```
<?php header('Location: success.php'); exit; ?>
```

Another is to use a session and to set some message you want to display and then display that message after you have redirected.

```
if($login){
  $_SESSION['login_message'] = "Your account has been logged in ".$newUser->username;
}

//after redirect
if(isset($_SESSION['login_message']){
  echo $_SESSION['login_message'];
}
```

You can also use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
//-->
</script>
```

in php:

```
<?php echo '<script>window.location = "http://www.google.com/"</script>'; ?>
```

The last method is to use a HTML redirect:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=http://www.w3schools.com" />
</head>

<body>
<p>Your message here, probably in php</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes - if you echo that out you can redirect with that. I missed another way which is using Javascript. Ill add that.

Comment: IMHO only the first should be **ever** used. Why should the users wait until the page loads and then again wait until JS finish executing:)

Comment: @Kieran:  You should always use an `exit;` after a call to `header()` when changing locations.  If you don't, the client receives the rest of the page contents in their browser.  If redirecting because a user isn't logged in, for example, this could be a security concern, depending on the page content.

Comment: What veritas said. In addition, some people might have javascript and meta redirects disabled.